# Assign a list to a pandas dataframe element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a column to a data frame, and also set a list to each element of it, after the execution of below code, nothing changed,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})  
df['C'] = 0 
for i in range(len(df)):
    lst = [6,7,8]
    data.iloc[i]['C'] = []
    data.iloc[i]['C'] = lst
```

Also, based on [Assigning a list value to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115686/assigning-a-list-value-to-pandas-dataframe), I tried df.at[i,'C'] on the above code, and the following error appeared: 'setting an array element with a sequence.'

Comment: Try changing the dtype of column C to object.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) with [`np.ndarray.tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)

```
l = len(df)
df['C'] = np.tile([6,7,8],(l,1)).tolist()
df
   A  B          C
0  1  4  [6, 7, 8]
1  2  5  [6, 7, 8]
2  3  6  [6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

One idea is use list comprehension:

```
lst = [6,7,8]

df['C'] = [lst for _ in df.index]

print (df)
   A  B          C
0  1  4  [6, 7, 8]
1  2  5  [6, 7, 8]
2  3  6  [6, 7, 8]
```

In your solution for me working:

```
df['C'] = ''
for i in range(len(df)):
    lst = [6,7,8]
    df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('C')] = lst
```